# Removing multiple select options and replace with new ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

I have a select tag like :

```
<span id="reportProjectSelector">
    <span>Reporting Project:</span>
    <select id="reportProjectDropdown" onChange="loadChartWithData();" multiple="multiple"></select>
</span>
```

and

```
$(function() {
    $('#reportProjectDropdown_${widgetId}').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
});
```

Here I have multiple dropdown chain of other dropdowns which are parents of 'reportProjectDropdown'. For simplicity let's consider just one 'Project'. So now we have 'Projects', on change of which 'Reporting Projects' filter is triggered. Currently the Reporting project filter doesn't change and replace new values (basically null or no values which are replaced by a value like 'No Reporting Projects' in the dropdown)

I have tried removing the previous values but with no luck. Here is the function that I am expecting will do the job.

```
function setDependentProjects (data, widgetId) {
    $('#reportProjectDropdown').find('option').remove().end();

    if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(data)) {
        let newOption = new Option("No Projects", 0, true, true);
        $('#reportProjectDropdown').append(newOption);
    } else {
        let selected = true;
        for(let key in data) {
            selected = "${defaultDependentProject}" == data[key];
            let newOption = new Option(data[key], key, selected, selected);
            $('#reportProjectDropdown').append(newOption);
            selected = false;
        }
    }

    loadChartWithData_${widgetId}(); //renders data as per the previous filters
}
```

Am I missing something or removing the elements incorrectly ?

Comment: Wherefrom setDependentProjects is called? Could you set up [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refresh the jQuery multiselect instance after every change. You can do that by using `$('#reportProjectDropdown').multiSelect('refresh');`

See also the documentation: [jQuery multiselect](http://loudev.com/)

Comment: I am getting 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).multiSelect is not a function', not sure why. I am already using the multiselect functionality. I have default inbuilt container that has bootstrap and multi-select libs

Comment: @Einstein_AB Seems like your not using the http://loudev.com/ multiselect libary then. What framework are you using?  multiselect is not a native jQuery function.

Comment: @Niklas.E. Isn't it the default multi-select for a HTML <select> tag. I just have added the attribute ' multiple' and the function to include the 'Select All option'

Comment: @Einstein_AB But you are using `$(...).multiselect(...)` in your question. This method of jQuery wasn't added by jQuery itself. It was added by an extension / a plugin for jQuery. What plugin was it? What jQuery plugins are you using? It is not the plugin from loudev.com otherwise you wouldn't get the error.

Comment: jQuery.multiselect.js is the lib.

Comment: I cannot finde a [other jQuery plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/multiselect/) than loudev.com. Provide a proper findable framework name and URL to it!

Comment: It was loudev.com indeed. I have solved this by some proper placement of and a call back method after removal and updates of the new options. Thanks for bearing me.

Comment: Let me get this straight. It was loudev.com but an outdated version of it? I would never have thought of that. But I'm glad to hear you solved your problem!